# hooking on WM_SETTEXT message

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I have setup a hook on WM_SETTEXT message using WH_CALLWNDPROC.

In hook procedure

```
CWPSTRUCT* info = (CWPSTRUCT*) lParam;
switch(info->message)
{
case WM_SETTEXT:
break;
}
```

Now in the above code how can I get the string that is passed along WM_SETTEXT message?
I am not able to get this information anywher..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lParam passed to WM_SETTEXT contains the string, so `info->lParam` should have the info you want.

Comment: This is correct.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632644(VS.85).aspx

lParam
Pointer to a null-terminated string that is the window text.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632644(VS.85).aspx

You should be able to get that with info->lParam.